# Flutter background service not running my phone

Tags: flutter, background-service

the problem I am experiencing is as follows. When I work through the emulator, the background service coding of my application works properly. However, when I install and run the application on my phone, the application does not open. I would be happy if you review my code and make suggestions.

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
static void _onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {

```
// Only available for flutter 3.0.0 and later
DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();

// For flutter prior to version 3.0.0
// We have to register the plugin manually

SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await preferences.setString("hello", "world");


if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
  service.on('setAsForeground').listen((event) {
    service.setAsForegroundService();
  });

  service.on('setAsBackground').listen((event) {
    service.setAsBackgroundService();
  });
}

service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
  service.stopSelf();
});

// bring to foreground
//int counter = 0;
int lastID = 0;
bool firstTimer = true;
Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) async {

  if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {

    if (await service.isForegroundService()) {
      //counter++;
      //
      // if you don't using custom notification, uncomment this
      String dataApiUrl ='http://10.150.3.192/api/resource/Arac%20Talep%20Formu?fields=["name", "employee_name","request_date","delivery_date","car_type","request_reason","mail","designation","phone_number","plate"]&limit_page_length=none&filters=[["plate","=",""]]';
      final String apiKey = '...';
      final String apiSecret = '...';

      final headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ${base64Encode(utf8.encode('$apiKey:$apiSecret'))}',
      };
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(dataApiUrl), headers: headers);

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {

        final jsonData = json.decode(response.body)['data'] as List<dynamic>;
        final dataListFromAPI =
        jsonData.map((json) => FrappeData.fromJson(json)).toList();
        var ids = dataListFromAPI.map((e) =>int.parse(e.name.split("-").last));
        var lastid = ids.last;

        if(firstTimer == false){
          if(lastid != lastID){
            LocalNotifications.showNotificationSimple(title: "CW ENERJİ", body: "Yeni Araç Talebi", payload: "payload");
            lastID = lastid;
          }
        }else{
          lastID = lastid;
          firstTimer = false;
        }
      }




      service.setForegroundNotificationInfo(
        title: "My App Service",
        content: "Updated at ${DateTime.now()}",
      );
    }
  }

  /// you can see this log in logcat
  print('FLUTTER BACKGROUND SERVICE: ${DateTime.now()}');

  // test using external plugin
  final deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
  String? device;
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    final androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
    device = androidInfo.model;
  }

  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    final iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
    device = iosInfo.model;
  }

  service.invoke(
    'update',
    {
      "current_date": DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
      "device": device,
    },
  );
});
```

}